# Using MySQL2 with Ruby gets me undefined local variable or method `client' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: mysql, ruby, methods, mysql2

So I've been working on some scraping scripts with Ruby, using the gem watir lately. I used to put the results in a .json file but I recently started working with MySQL2. So here's the deal:

I have created a db called scrap, with a table called links, which has 3 columns: id, job, link. The script I'm working on for this is very simple: it makes a query on google search, takes the URLs of all the links, then goes to the next page. So here's the boy:

```
require "watir"
require "json"
require "mysql2"
b = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => "xxx", :database => "scrap", :encoding => "utf8")


def Launch(b)
  job = "cabinet avocat"
  ville = "paris"
  k = 0
  j = "avocat"
  b.goto "https://www.google.fr/search?q="+"#{job}"+" "+"#{ville}" "&dcr=0&ei=1-quWY6BDouYgAb0tZq4CA&start="+"#{k}"+"&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=876"

  loop do
    l0 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:0).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l0}')");

    l1 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:1).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l1}')");

    l2 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:2).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l2}')");

    l3 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:3).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l3}')");

    l4 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:4).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l4}')");

    l5 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:5).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l5}')");

    l6 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:6).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l6}')");

    l7 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:7).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l7}')");

    l8 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:8).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l8}')");

    l9 = b.div(class:"f kv _SWb", index:9).text
    client.query("INSERT INTO links(job, link)
    VALUES('#{j}, '#{l9}')");

    k += 10
    b.goto "https://www.google.fr/search?q="+"#{job}"+" "+"#{ville}" "&dcr=0&ei=1-quWY6BDouYgAb0tZq4CA&start="+"#{k}"+"&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=876"
    break if k == 200
  end
end

Launch(b)
```

As you can see it's very messy, but I'm aware of that and this will be fixed as soon as I get it to work. So when I run it, that's the error I get:

```
test.rb:17:in `block in Launch': undefined local variable or method `client' for main:Object (NameError)
    from test.rb:15:in `loop'
    from test.rb:15:in `Launch'
    from test.rb:62:in `<main>'
```

I have searched pretty much everywhere and haven't been able to find a solution to my problem, which is why I created an account here in order to not only look at the questions at others, but post my own.

Thank you everyone

Comment: Given where `client` is declared, it is not available to the `Launch` method. You want to either (1) move the declaration of `client` into the `Launch` method or (2) redefine the method to pass client as a parameter - ie `Launch(b, client)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client` is out of scope Launch method.

Make it global `@client` or assign as second attribute in `Launch(b, launch)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I answered back but I'm not sure you'll get a notification from it, so I'm commenting too.

Comment: No worries - mark it if described issue is resolved.